# HTML5 Pattern match numeric values (integer,float positive or negative) , TRS or PCB ignore case?

Tags: regex, html

I need my pattern to match any numeric value not greater than 3 digits. Can be decimal with no more than 2 digits after the period. Numeric values can be positive or negative. Last two values that should be accepted should be either TRS or PCB. I would like to ignore the case for these two values. So if user type `TRS` or `trs` both would be accepted. Here is what I have so far:

```
[+-]?[0-9]+([\.][0-9]{0,2})[TRS][trs][PBC][pbc]?
```

For some reason my numeric values are not accepted. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a list of expected valid and invalid inputs? Also, do you need to capture a certain part of the string or just match the whole thing?

Comment: A few quick pointers: `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d`; `[\.]` is redundant with `[.]`, which is actually just redundant with `\.`; and depending on the language you're using, you might be able to enable a case-insensitive switch (typically `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern), which will make the match much simpler for the letters at the end.

Comment: @CAustin Valid value is any numeric value from -999 to 999 or full matching string for DNT or CNT ignore case sensitive. Does that make sense? Numeric values can be decimal like 10.56 or 956.45 or -578.6

Comment: @espresso_coffee Is 999.99 a valid value in your case?

Comment: Adding a clear list of examples of matches and non-matches to the question would help a lot. How are `TRS` and `PCB` related to `CNT` and `DNT`? Is the `TRS`/`PCB` mandatory or optional and, if it is mandatory, should it be part of the matched value or should just the numeric section be matched? Would a value such as 1.234 be rejected or should it match the 1.23 part? Would something like `1234` be rejected while `A234` would match the 234? Your RegExp implies a leading `+` would also be acceptable, is that correct? What should match for `123.ABC`, just the `123` or should it include the `.`?

Comment: By **HTML5** do you mean the `pattern` attribute of an `<input>` element? If that's what you meant then it answers some of the question in my previous comment because the 'match' has to be everything.

Comment: 999.99 is not a valid value since is greater than 999. Yes this is HTML5 pattern regex that I need.

Comment: @skirtle Values that should be accepted are TRS or trs, PCB or pcb, numeric values like 123.45 or 123. If user enters 123. that should not be accepted. Only - sign should be accepted since that will indicate negative numbers. Only two digits after the period are allowed.

Comment: @espresso_coffee I have updated the answer. Also, in one of the comments, you mentioned only negative numbers are allowed whereas you yourself have used `[+-]?' in your regex thus allowing positive numbers too. clarify on that too.

Comment: @Gurman I do not need + in front of the number but I do need - for negative numbers.

Comment: @espresso_coffee I have updated the code and the Demo link. Test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!\s*$)(?:TRS|PCB|[-]?999|[-]?(?:(?:[1-8]\d{2}|9\d[1-8]|[1-9]\d|\d)?(?:\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d))?))$
```

[Click here for DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WFg0ik/5)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of the String
- `(?!\s*$)` - Negative lookahead to avoid matching the strings containing ONLY 0+ spaces
- `(?:TRS|PCB|[+-]?999|[-+]?(?:(?:[1-8]\d{2}|9\d[1-8]|[1-9]\d|\d)?(?:\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]))?))` - Matches Either `TRS` or `PCB` or the required numeric value(break-up provided below). To make it case-insensitive, use `/i` as shown in the Demo link
- `[-]?999` - Matches 0 or 1 occurrence of either `-` followed by 999
- `(?:[1-8]\d{2}|9\d[1-8]|[1-9]\d|\d)?` - Matches the required 3/2/1 digit number before decimal point. It is optional because we can have values starting with the decimal point.
- `(?:\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d))?` - matches 2 digits after the decimal point. It is made optional to match the integral values too.
- `$` - End of the String

Comment: Very odd is when I use this in HTML5 pattern lower case TRS and PCB are not accepted as valid...

Comment: @espresso_coffee Then you can try adding them to the OR(`|`) list as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/WFg0ik/6